# HDInsight emulator - How to run locally a MapReduce job based on C# executables

Tags: c#, hadoop, emulation, azure-hdinsight

I have installed the HDInsight emulator and I have also defined the azure storage emulator (blob) as the default hdfs. Could you please inform me how to run locally a mapreduce job that it is implemented in C#? I have uploaded the executables in the blob. Could you also give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

The emulator hasn't been updated for a long time.  if you are new to the technology, you might want to start using the Linux-based HDInsight cluster instead.  Here is the article to follow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-emulator-get-started.  Please note Linux-based HDInsight doesn't support C# streaming.